# QueryString Structure of a Conditial Retrieve in OneM2M?

Tags: onem2m

This is an example resource tree.

I need to retrieve latest 48 hours' data of **cnt-2** and **cnt-0** all together. What kind of query string should I put to the request ?

```
/in-cse
   /in-cse/ae-123
      /in-cse/cnt-2
         /in-cse/cin-21
         /in-cse/cin-22
         /in-cse/cin-23
   /in-cse/ae-124
      /in-cse/cnt-0
         /in-cse/cin-01
         /in-cse/cin-02
         /in-cse/cin-03
      /in-cse/cnt-1
         /in-cse/cin-11
         /in-cse/cin-22
         /in-cse/cin-33
```

Where should I put the **id**s of cnt-0 and cnt-2 in the querystring ?

**/onem2m/api/v1/~/in-cse?fu=2&crb=20190808T000000&cra=20190806T000000&ty=4**

Also should I use only querystring to make discovery or is it valid to make a POST request ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the example request in your question you will also get all the matching <contentInstance> resources of *cnt-1*, because you do the discovery on the level of the IN-CSE. Unfortunately, you cannot have multiple targets in a single request, but I see at least two solutions that could work for your use case:

- You can add labels two <contentInstance> resources and add label to your search.
  `/onem2m/api/v1/~/in-cse?fu=2&crb=20190808T000000&cra=20190806T000000&label=myLabel&ty=4`
- You can add a <group> that contains the <container> resources that are important to your use case (ie. *cnt-0* and *cnt-2*) and make the <group>'s fanoutPoint the target of your discovery request. The CSE is then responsible to redirect the discovery to each member of the <group>.
  `/onem2m/api/v1/~/in-cse/aGroup/fopt?fu=2&crb=20190808T000000&cra=20190806T000000&ty=4`

In my opinion the second method is the more "elegant" one because it makes the (application) relationship of the two <container> resources clearer , but the first one might also be feasible if your <contentInstance> resources are tagged using labels anyway.

Regarding the POST request: For the HTTP binding query parameters are only allowed for filtering and discovery. Please have a look at TS-0009, section *6.2.2.2 Query component*.

Btw, there are currently ongoing discussions in oneM2M to describe the differences between retrieval and discovery a bit better.

Comment: Yes. Also the terminology makes it more difficult to understand because retrieval seems to be part of discovery regarding to OneM2M. I think the distinction should be more clear. 

Making multiple requests are affecting performance too much. We should find a workaround for that. Thanks for the quick reply and your nice opinions.